# Maximum file size on Windows platform

Tags: windows, c++, visual-c++

According to [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Limitations), the size of a individual file on Win10 can go up to about 8 PB with NTFS. Yet the struct Stat is defined as

```c
struct stat
{
    _dev_t         st_dev;
    _ino_t         st_ino;
    unsigned short st_mode;
    short          st_nlink;
    short          st_uid;
    short          st_gid;
    _dev_t         st_rdev;
    _off_t         st_size;
    time_t         st_atime;
    time_t         st_mtime;
    time_t         st_ctime;
};
```

where off_t is type defined as long. That means a roughly 4 GB limit. According to [this stackoverflow page](https://superuser.com/questions/398346/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-file-size-for-ntfs-partitions), even for 32-bit OS, the size of a file can be larger than it.

Unless I have mistaken something, how can one use struct stat to get the size of a file reliably. Furthermore, what will happen if the file size exceeds the limit of the long type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should rather use the 64-bit versions of the
[stat functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=vs-2017).

The `__stat64` structure from the `stat.h` include file:

```c
struct _stat64
{
    _dev_t         st_dev;
    _ino_t         st_ino;
    unsigned short st_mode;
    short          st_nlink;
    short          st_uid;
    short          st_gid;
    _dev_t         st_rdev;
    __int64        st_size;
    __time64_t     st_atime;
    __time64_t     st_mtime;
    __time64_t     st_ctime;
};
```

In here `st_size` is `__int64` which is 64-bit and not 32-bit.

Comment: Thanks. I thought __stat64 is for 64-bit OS.

Comment: If you are on a 32-bit system you can still use the [GetFileSize function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesize).

Comment: That is exactly I am looking for